# Kivy not loading images on Android app, despite their paths existing

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

I am creating an app that downloads manga from 4 different sites ([My Project's Github Link](https://github.com/Gaysha1337/IAs/tree/master/CS_IA_Manga_Downloader_Kivy)). The user can also read the manga from within the app. This done by having the user select a manga on a screen, which will take them to a new screen with buttons for each chapter. When the user clicks a chapter button, they are taken to a new screen with a carousel that stores all the images in a bunch of slides. My problem is that on Android, when I download one particular manga, the images don't show up, but instead a white square does. I have to tried to reload the images, but that does not seem to be working.

It may be worth mentioning that in previous versions, I would download the manga to app's private directory (in Kivy that is: `self.user_data_dir`), instead I now write to the primary external storage. Note, that I have requested the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in both my `buildozer.spec` and `main.py` files.

Buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Manga Downloader

# (str) Package name
package.name = mangadownloader

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.mangadownloader

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
#source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ini,ttf, otf

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png, DATA/*

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = UIX, Feature_Testing,

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
# kivy==2.0.0rc4 = https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
# kivymd==0.104.2.dev0 = https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
# kivymd (version that displays icons on android): git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git
# os,json,re,threading,pathlib,shutil,
# bs4
requirements = python3==3.8.5,hostpython3==3.8.5,openssl,android,python-for-android,kivy==2.0.0rc4,git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,Pillow,pygments,tqdm,pykakasi,klepto,dill,pox,plyer,natsort,lxml,bs4,beautifulsoup4,soupsieve,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,certifi,simplejson

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/Icons/MangaDownloaderIcon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.8.5

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0rc4

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = APP

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Throughout my code, I use this one function: `resource_path()`:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    # Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

I will include the code resposible for loading the chapters and the images:

```
class MangaReaderChapterSelection(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, master, title, manga_path, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.manga_path = resource_path(manga_path)
        self.manga_title = title
        self.effect_cls = "ScrollEffect"
        self.bar_width = "10dp"
        self.pos_hint = {"top":.9}
        self.padding=("20dp", "0dp", "20dp", "0dp") # padding: [padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom]
        
        # Get all the chapter directories and sort them alphanumerically
        self.chapter_dirs = os_sorted([os.path.abspath(resource_path(dir)) for dir in glob(os.path.join(self.manga_path,"*/")) if os.path.isdir(dir)])
        self.grid = MDStackLayout(adaptive_height=True,padding=("30dp", "50dp", "30dp", "0dp"), spacing="20dp", pos_hint={"center_x":.5})

        # Loop to create buttons for each chapter of a manga
        for chapter_dir in self.chapter_dirs:
            chapter_name = os.path.basename(resource_path(chapter_dir))
 
            def reload_func(manga_title = self.manga_title, name=chapter_name, path=chapter_dir):
                self.master.create_manga_reader(manga_title, name, path) 

            self.chapter_btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text=chapter_name, pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.8}, 
                on_release = partial(kill_screen, "Manga Reader Carousel", reload_func),
            )
            self.grid.add_widget(self.chapter_btn)
        self.add_widget(self.grid)

class ZoomableImage(ScatterPlane):
    def __init__(self, image_src, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_resize=Clock.schedule_once(self.center_it))
        self.image_src = image_src
        self.do_translation = self.do_rotation = False 
        self.do_scale = True 
        self.scale = self.scale_min= 5
        self.scale_max= 16
        self.size_hint=(None,None)
        self.manga_img = MangaImage(source = self.image_src, keep_ratio = False, allow_stretch = True, nocache=True)
        
        if platform == "android":
            try:
                print("image reloaded")
                self.manga_img.remove_from_cache()
                self.manga_img.reload()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Image Reload Exception: ", e)
        
        Clock.schedule_once(self.center_it)
        self.add_widget(self.manga_img)

    def center_it(self, inst):
        self.center = self.parent.center

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # Override Scatter's `on_touch_down` behavior for mouse scroll
        if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
            if touch.button == 'scrolldown' and self.scale < 10: self.scale = self.scale * 1.1
            
            elif touch.button == 'scrollup' and self.scale > 1: self.scale = self.scale * 0.8
        # If some other kind of "touch": Fall back on Scatter's behavior
        else:
            super().on_touch_down(touch)
    
class MangaCarousel(Carousel):
    def __init__(self, direction, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.direction = direction

    def on_index(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for child in self.current_slide.walk_reverse(loopback=True):
            if isinstance(child, ZoomableImage):
                child.scale = child.scale_min
                Clock.schedule_once(child.center_it)
        super().on_index(*args, **kwargs)


class MangaReaderCarouselContainer(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, master, manga_title,chapter_name,chapter_path,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.manga_title = manga_title
        self.chapter_name = chapter_name
        self.chapter_path = resource_path(chapter_path)
        self.padding=("0dp", "100dp", "0dp", "20dp") # padding: [padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom]
        
        self.chapter_imgs = os_sorted([
            resource_path(img) for img in glob(os.path.join(self.chapter_path, "*.jpg")) 
            if os.path.isfile(resource_path(img))    
        ])

        # Debug:
        if platform == "android":
            print(f"Chapter images of {self.manga_title}: {self.chapter_imgs}")                
        
        self.swiping_direction = "left" if self.master.manga_swiping_direction == "Left to Right (Japanese style)" else "right"
        self.reading_direction = "bottom" if self.master.manga_reading_direction == "Scroll vertically" else self.swiping_direction
        
        #self.carousel = Carousel(direction=self.reading_direction)
        self.carousel = MangaCarousel(direction=self.reading_direction)
        
        
        for index, img in enumerate(self.chapter_imgs):
            self.scatter = ZoomableImage(image_src=resource_path(img))

            self.inner_carousel_layout = MDRelativeLayout()#size=self.scatter.size)
            self.inner_carousel_layout.add_widget(MDLabel(text=f"Page {index + 1}/{len(self.chapter_imgs)}", pos_hint={"top":.6}))
            
            self.inner_carousel_layout.add_widget(self.scatter)
            self.carousel.add_widget(self.inner_carousel_layout)
    
            self.prev_btn = MDIconButton(icon="menu-left", user_font_size ="200sp", on_release = lambda *x :self.carousel.load_previous(), pos_hint={"center_x":.1, "center_y":.5}) 
            self.next_btn = MDIconButton(icon="menu-right", user_font_size ="200sp", on_release = lambda *x:self.carousel.load_next(), pos_hint={"center_x":.9, "center_y":.5})
            
            # Changes the way the arrows load the pages depending on the reading direction
            # True/left --> Left to right (left)  JP ; False/right --> Right to left (right) EN
            if self.swiping_direction == "left" and self.reading_direction != "bottom":
                self.prev_btn = MDIconButton(icon="menu-left", user_font_size ="200sp", on_release = lambda *x:self.carousel.load_next(), pos_hint={"center_x":.1, "center_y":.5}) 
                self.next_btn = MDIconButton(icon="menu-right", user_font_size ="200sp", on_release = lambda *x:self.carousel.load_previous(), pos_hint={"center_x":.9, "center_y":.5}) 

            if platform != "android": 
                self.inner_carousel_layout.add_widget(self.prev_btn)
                self.inner_carousel_layout.add_widget(self.next_btn)

        self.add_widget(self.carousel)
```

Below is the output of my `adb logcat *:S python:D`.

```
03-07 23:08:35.259 28993 30897 I python  : [INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
03-07 23:08:35.451 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is not available
03-07 23:08:49.346 28993 30897 I python  : Chapter images of 0.01200426899958984: ['/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 335.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 336.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 337.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 338.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 339.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 340.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 341.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 342.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 343.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 344.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 345.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 346.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 347.jpg', '/storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 348.jpg']
03-07 23:08:49.679 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 335.jpg>
03-07 23:08:49.679 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 335.jpg>
03-07 23:08:49.680 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:49.974 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 335.jpg>
03-07 23:08:49.974 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 335.jpg>
03-07 23:08:50.464 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 336.jpg>
03-07 23:08:50.464 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 336.jpg>
03-07 23:08:50.465 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:50.928 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 336.jpg>
03-07 23:08:50.929 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 336.jpg>
03-07 23:08:51.450 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 337.jpg>
03-07 23:08:51.451 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 337.jpg>
03-07 23:08:51.451 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:51.925 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 337.jpg>
03-07 23:08:51.925 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 337.jpg>
03-07 23:08:52.475 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 338.jpg>
03-07 23:08:52.476 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 338.jpg>
03-07 23:08:52.476 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:52.956 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 338.jpg>
03-07 23:08:52.957 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 338.jpg>
03-07 23:08:53.550 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 339.jpg>
03-07 23:08:53.551 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 339.jpg>
03-07 23:08:53.552 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:54.017 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 339.jpg>
03-07 23:08:54.018 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 339.jpg>
03-07 23:08:54.559 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 340.jpg>
03-07 23:08:54.560 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 340.jpg>
03-07 23:08:54.561 28993 30897 I python  : image reloaded
03-07 23:08:55.027 28993 30897 I python  : [WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 340.jpg>
03-07 23:08:55.028 28993 30897 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading </storage/emulated/0/Manga/Raw Japanese Manga/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden/Chapter 4/Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden Chapter 4 - 340.jpg>
```

If anyone knows why this may be happening or what can be done, please let me know.

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: I have posted my buildozer.spec, if that helps. I set my target API to be 27 (min API is 21), the SDK version is 20

Answer (score 0):

Through some divine miracle, I managed to display the images. All I needed to do was to insert at the top of my `main.py` file:

```
import os, sys, plyer

# This needs to be here to display the manga images on Android
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'pil,sdl2'
```

Comment: Great. But you still did not tell what a manga would be. Never heard of.

Comment: I was trying to download: Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute! Shadow Gaiden from a website called rawdevart.com, it was the only manga that showed white images. The reset displayed perfectly.

Comment: You understood wrong. The question was: What is a manga?

Comment: It is a Japanese comic book, [Wikipedia: Manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga)

Comment: Adding the lines above did not work for me. It makes my app crash.

Comment: @Jortega, you may not have installed the Pillow library, run `pip install pillow`. Also, that line needs to be imported before any of the Kivy libraries are imported [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72471312/8753747).

Comment: @Dimitriy Kruglikov Thank you for the comment, still no luck. Trying make this work on andriod
 `AsyncImage:
source: 'https://www.some-image-address`

Comment: @Jortega, have a look at this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1827#issuecomment-500028459)